# Are there any patterns for monitoring log4net exception logs from across a cluster of web servers?

Tags: asp.net, log4net, web-farm

Are there any patterns or practices for monitoring log4net exception logs across a cluster of web servers. I have considered several options including the following:

- A central database
- A log file retrieval system
- A service based loggin architecture

Thanks, 
Richard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Message Queuing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.messaging.messagequeue.aspx) is a great solution. It works great in a distributed enviroment where one machine or multiple can be popping log messages of the queue and persisting them somewhere (Central logging database or rolling flat files...). And if at any time a machine creating messages or popping go offline they can continue logging messages and continue as normal when they are back online.

Answer (score 0):

Your could configure log4net to trace into the event log of each machine and use a hypervisor software such as [SCOM](http://www.microsoft.com/systemcenter/en/us/operations-manager.aspx) to monitor each node.